# How to pass a variable from a command button action on a user form to a module in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, global-variables, userform

I am new to the board. I have a module in VBA for Excel and an associated user form with 4 CommandButtons. I call the user form with `frmSelect.Show`. The user is to pick on 1 of the 4 Command buttons and then a value is assigned to a variable that I want to pass to the module. This way I can tell which CommandButton was activated. I cannot seem to figure out how to pass a variable as the variable always comes back to the module as a null (0).

This is the module code:

```
Sub BumpGenerator()
Dim Pattern As Integer
frmSelect.Show
If Pattern = 1 then 
    Do some stuff
End If
If Pattern = 2 then 
    Do some other stuff
End If
If Pattern = 3 then 
    Do some other stuff
End If
If Pattern = 4 then
    Do this stuff
End If
End Sub
```

This is the code in the user form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Pattern = 1
frmSelect.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Pattern = 2
frmSelect.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Pattern = 3
frmSelect.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Pattern = 4
frmSelect.Hide
End Sub
```

I have tried using:

1. 'Public Pattern As Integer' above my module
2. Passing Pattern as a variable using 'BumpGenerator(Pattern As Integer)'
3. Using 'Call BumpGenerator(Pattern)' in the user form
4. Using 'BumpGenerator Value:=Pattern'

but none of those options changed my null.

Thank you for any replies

Answer (score 1):

Forms are just a special type of class so you can do with forms anything you can do with a class.

In your userform define a UDT which holds the values of you module level variables.

```
Private Type State
    Pattern as Long
End Type

Private s   as State

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    s.Pattern = 1
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    s.Pattern = 2
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    s.Pattern = 3
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    s.Pattern = 4
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Public Property Get Pattern() as long
    Pattern = s.Pattern
End Property

' and then in your module
Sub BumpGenerator()

    frmSelect.Show

    ' You don't lose access to the form just because you've hidden it.
    Select Case frmSelect.Pattern  
        Case 1
            Do some stuff

        Case 2 
            Do some other stuff
     
        Case 3 
            Do some other stuff

        Case 4 
            Do this stuff

     End Select
End Sub
```

By the way, you should be aware that you are making a classic newbie mistake as you are using the default instance of frmSelect rather than creating a specific instance of the form.  This is why you can use frmSelect.Hide rather than Me.Hide.

Its much better (in the longer run) to create your own instances of forms.

```
Dim mySelect as frmSelect
Set mySelect = New frmSelect
etc....
```

I'd also suggest that you install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the Code Inspections

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable Pattern `global` than your code works.
I would also recommend to have a look at the [scoping rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) of vba.

1. User-Form modul

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Pattern = 1
    BumpGenerator
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Pattern = 2
    BumpGenerator
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Pattern = 3
    BumpGenerator
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Pattern = 4
    BumpGenerator
End Sub
```

2. Standard modul

```vb
Option Explicit

Global Pattern As Integer

Sub BumpGenerator()

    Debug.Print Pattern
    frmselect.Hide

End Sub
```